# SD card vs USB stick: best secondary storage for sudden shutdowns projects

Tags: usb, sd-card, power, storage

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Raspbian Stretch Lite on a read-only SD card which periodically saves files on the secondary storage.
Since there will be sudden shutdowns I'm wondering which device is better as secondary storage, someone told me USB sticks are better for this purpose, but they couldn't give me a reason.
is it true and why?

Answer (score 1):

It makes little difference.

It is more significant how the storage is formatted. FAT has many limitations, but is less likely to corrupt files.

ext4 is more suitable for large files and is journaled, so better at recovery if damaged.

Comment: the files are images of about 1MB, I'm using NTFS because is Windows compatible and is journaled, can you explain me what is this little difference?

Comment: The Linux NTFS implementation is not journaled

Comment: Do you mean the ntfs-3g package? So FAT should be better for my application? I'd use a SD card if there is no difference

Comment: or is there a journaled NTFS implementation for Raspbian?